# Update PySide6 element

Tags: python-3.x, pyside6, qt6

I'm learning Qt6 through PySide6 using Python.

I've created this example of code to ask my question:

```py
class Test(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.list_dns = ['www.doesnotexi.st', 'www.google.com']
        self.list_label = []

        group_box = QGroupBox("DNS")
        layout = QVBoxLayout()

        for server in self.list_dns:
            server_line = QHBoxLayout()
            server_label = QLabel(server)
            server_line.addWidget(server_label)
            server_led = QLabel()
            led_pixmap = QPixmap("images/led_grey.png")
            server_led.setPixmap(led_pixmap)
            server_line.addWidget(server_led, alignment=Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignRight)
            layout.addLayout(server_line)
            self.list_label.append(server_line)

        group_box.setLayout(layout)

        layout2 = QVBoxLayout()
        layout2.addWidget(group_box)

        test_button = QPushButton("Test DNS", self)
        test_button.clicked.connect(self.test_dns)

        layout2.addWidget(test_button)

        central_widget = QWidget()
        central_widget.setLayout(layout2)
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

    def test_dns(self):
        server_line = QHBoxLayout()
        server_label = QLabel('www.doesnotexi.st')
        server_line.addWidget(server_label)
        server_led = QLabel()
        led_pixmap = QPixmap("images/led_red.png")
        server_led.setPixmap(led_pixmap)
        server_line.addWidget(server_led, alignment=Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignRight)
        self.list_label.pop(0)
        self.list_label.insert(0, server_line)
```

Producing this:

[image: GUI of the above code]

When I click on the button, I expect to replace the 'doesnotexi.st' line with a RED led.

Instead, nothing happens. I clearly don't understand how I should do.

What I would reach is either to replace de Pixmap object, or remove the entire QHBoxLayout (server_line) to recreate it with the updated Pixmap.

If the 2nd solution is suggested, I would like to keep the exact same order in the QGroupBox.

If you have some example of open-source software (PySide6 + Python3) I can read to learn and understand how it works, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Use a dictionary with server names as keywords and labels as values.

Comment: My `self.list_label` is now a dictionnary. During the `for server` loop, I'm adding the QHBoxLayout in my dict: `self.list_label[server] = server_line` and adding the dictionnary element in the layout: `layout.addLayout(self.list_label[server])`. On my test_dns function, I'm recreation the entire QHBoxLayout then affecting it to the entry in the dict: `self.list_label['www.doesnotexi.st'] = new_server_line`. It does not work...

Comment: I will try another method: In a first time, I'll fill a dictionary with grey led for each element. Then I'll create the GUI with this dictionary. In the test_dns function, I'll update the dictionary then remove a high-level element in the GUI then create again the GUI. All functions to create the GUI will remain intact, but will use different data. As is, my GUI should be updated.

Comment: There is absolutely no need to always recreate the whole layout. Just create the UI *along with* the dictionary, then cycle through the server list and just update the labels with the new pixmaps.

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd method I tried works in my example:

```py
class Test(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # Initialize the App with initial data
        self.list_dns = {
            'www.doesnotexi.st': 'grey',
            'www.google.com': 'grey'
        }

        # Create the high-level Qt element
        self.layout2 = QVBoxLayout()

        # Create the GUI
        self.create_gui()

    def create_gui(self):
        group_box = QGroupBox("DNS")
        layout = QVBoxLayout()

        for server in self.list_dns:
            server_line = QHBoxLayout()

            server_label = QLabel(server)
            server_line.addWidget(server_label)

            server_led = QLabel()
            led_pixmap = QPixmap("images/led_" + self.list_dns[server] + ".png")
            server_led.setPixmap(led_pixmap)
            server_line.addWidget(server_led, alignment=Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignRight)

            layout.addLayout(server_line)

        group_box.setLayout(layout)
        self.layout2.addWidget(group_box)
        test_button = QPushButton("Test DNS", self)
        test_button.clicked.connect(self.test_dns)
        self.layout2.addWidget(test_button)
        central_widget = QWidget()
        central_widget.setLayout(self.layout2)
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

    def test_dns(self):
        # Modify data
        self.list_dns['www.doesnotexi.st'] = "red"

        # Delete the high-level Qt element
        self.layout2 = QVBoxLayout()

        # Re-create the GUI
        self.create_gui()
```

The result is:

[image: Animated picture of the result]